# How do I convert from a money datatype in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, currency

I have a money data type in SQL Server. How do I reformat 0.00 to 0 in my query?

Comment: Provide more detail and you might get some answers.

Comment: Just **cast or convert** to `int or bigint`

Answer (score 34):

Normal money conversions will preserve individual pennies:

```
SELECT convert(varchar(30), moneyfield, 1)
```

The last parameter decides what the output format looks like:

0 (default) No commas every three digits to the left of the decimal point, and two digits to the right of the decimal point; for example, 4235.98.

1 Commas every three digits to the left of the decimal point, and two digits to the right of the decimal point; for example, 3,510.92.

2 No commas every three digits to the left of the decimal point, and four digits to the right of the decimal point; for example, 4235.9819.

If you want to truncate the pennies, and count in pounds, you can use rounding to the nearest pound, floor to the lowest whole pound, or ceiling to round up the pounds:

```
SELECT convert(int, round(moneyfield, 0))
SELECT convert(int, floor(moneyfield))
SELECT convert(int, ceiling(moneyfield))
```

Comment: This will work if you want to discard all penny values, and not JUST when it's 0.00.  See my answer for that.

Answer (score 3):

Would casting it to int help you?  Money is meant to have the decimal places...

```
DECLARE @test AS money
SET @test = 3
SELECT CAST(@test AS int), @test
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should never use the money datatype. If you do any calculations you will get truncated results. Run the following to see what I mean

```
DECLARE
    @mon1 MONEY,
    @mon2 MONEY,
    @mon3 MONEY,
    @mon4 MONEY,
    @num1 DECIMAL(19,4),
    @num2 DECIMAL(19,4),
    @num3 DECIMAL(19,4),
    @num4 DECIMAL(19,4)

    SELECT
    @mon1 = 100, @mon2 = 339, @mon3 = 10000,
    @num1 = 100, @num2 = 339, @num3 = 10000

    SET @mon4 = @mon1/@mon2*@mon3
    SET @num4 = @num1/@num2*@num3

    SELECT @mon4 AS moneyresult,
    @num4 AS numericresult
```

Output:
2949.0000    2949.8525

Now to answer your question (it was a little vague), the money datatype always has two places after the decimal point. Use the integer datatype if you don't want the fractional part or convert to int.

Perhaps you want to use the decimal or numeric datatype?

Comment: Microsoft Dynamics uses the money data type. I saw that today.

Comment: How valid is it really to want to multiple $450.50 * $32.76, I sat here for a while thinking of any time I would actually want to multiple money values together, or divide them. I used your example sql and changed the */ to use +- and even wrapped those in a * and / and the values for each matched.

Comment: For the detailed comments on this answer, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582797/should-you-choose-the-money-or-decimalx-y-datatypes-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

It seems despite the intrinsic limitations of the money datatype, if you're already using it (or have inherited it as I have) the answer to your question is, use DECIMAL.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT PARSENAME('$'+ Convert(varchar,Convert(money,@MoneyValue),1),2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this [approach](http://www.onceinaweb.com/23/web-and-database-development/convertvarchar10-convertmoney-cprice-as-price-was-all-it-took) direct and useful.

CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(MONEY, fieldname)) AS PRICE

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well, and was tripped up for a while on it.  I wanted to display 0.00 as 0 and otherwise keep the decimal point.  The following didn't work:

```
CASE WHEN Amount= 0 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), Amount, 1) ELSE Amount END
```

Because the resulting column was forced to be a MONEY column.  To resolve it, the following worked

```
CASE WHEN Amount= 0 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), '0', 1) ELSE CONVERT (VARCHAR(30), Amount, 1) END
```

This mattered because my final destination column was a VARCHAR(30), and the consumers of that column would error out if an amount was '0.00' instead of '0'.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a formating issue to me.
As far as SQL Server's money type is concerned 0 == 0.00

If you're trying to display 0 in say c# rather then 0.00 you should convert it to a string, and format it as you want. (or truncate it.)

Answer (score 0):

you could either use

```
SELECT PARSENAME('$'+ Convert(varchar,Convert(money,@MoneyValue),1),2)
```

or

```
SELECT CurrencyNoDecimals = '$'+ LEFT( CONVERT(varchar, @MoneyValue,1),    
       LEN (CONVERT(varchar, @MoneyValue,1)) - 2)
```