# Rounding off in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to round off a number of data type numeric nearest to 2 places in SQL Server

Eg.,

```
Input:  123.10000000
Output: 123.10
```

Thanks and Regards,
Ismail

Answer (score 6):

You will need to convert it:

`Select Convert(numeric(19,2), @value)`

You can use the [Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) function too to perform the rounding:

`Select Round(@Value, 2)`

Answer (score 2):

Would `CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,2), ROUND(123.10000000, 2))` do the trick?

Comment: @Andriy - `money` converts it to 4 decimal places though doesn't it? So the output would be 123.1000

Comment: @Barry: No, it wouldn't as long as the value is rounded to 2 decimal places.

Comment: @Andriy & Barry: Can I draw your attention to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582797/should-you-choose-the-money-or-decimalx-y-datatypes-in-sql-server

Comment: @Ardman: Thank you. `money` has got a fixed and quite limited precision, that is a fact well documented. Behind the stage `money` is essentially a 64-bit integer whose last 4 digits are simply displayed as decimals. Being aware of that helps people to be cautious when manipulating such data. Being unaware of that causes people to call it 'pure garbage'.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
select round(123.10000000, 2)
```

or

```
select cast(123.10000000 as decimal(12,2))
```

Comment: Your second approach now seems to me the best one, as it both gets rid of the extra decimal places and, as it turns out, implicitly rounds the value. (I first thought it would truncate it.)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(InputValue, 2) AS money) AS OutputValue
```