# What was the rationale behind the Money datatype?

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should you choose the MONEY or DECIMAL(x,y) datatypes in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582797/should-you-choose-the-money-or-decimalx-y-datatypes-in-sql-server)

I can't see why you would use the `money` datatype over `decimal`, apart from stripping currency symbols, it seems equivalent to a decimal with a scale of 4.

Am I missing something?

---

Update: What was the rationale behind introducing `Money` datatype? Rather that arguing about whether you should divide `money` by `money` which is what the other question seemed to boil down to.

Answer (score 0):

"Syntactic sugar about stripping currency symbols"? - SQL Server doesn't store currency symbols. And it has nothing to do with a compiler doing fancy compile time tricks, which is what "syntactic sugar" refers to. The decimal type is a precise data type and money is not, beyond four decimal places or so. It depends on your needs. You probably can't go wrong just using a decimal type.