# Money column practical is sql? How to insert with EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should you choose the MONEY or DECIMAL(x,y) datatypes in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582797/should-you-choose-the-money-or-decimalx-y-datatypes-in-sql-server)

I have a column that I want to keep track of money.

1) Is a money column practical for keeping track of money or do people use decimal instead?

2) In my .edmx file I cant seem to change my column to Money, its simply just not an option in the properties window.

3) If I do use money or decimal, how do I cast it into the database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should you choose the MONEY or DECIMAL(x,y) datatypes in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582797/should-you-choose-the-money-or-decimalx-y-datatypes-in-sql-server) and quite a few others - has been answered at length...