# difference between money and integer data type

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, types

what's the difference between money and bigint data type in sql server?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Range/Precision

`bigint` range is `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`

`money` range is `-922,337,203,685,477.5808` to `922,337,203,685,477.5807`

### Storage

They both take 8 bytes of storage and are stored as big integers the only difference is that SQL Server understands that the 4 right most digits are after the decimal point.

If you do

```
declare @m money = 1.2345
declare @b bigint = 12345

select cast(@m as BINARY(8)), cast(@b as BINARY(8))
```

You see the storage is the same.

```
------------------ ------------------
0x0000000000003039 0x0000000000003039
```

### Behaviour

However the `money` datatype does not behave exactly as though you were to just use a `bigint` yourself. Calculations  with `money` [are to be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582797/should-you-choose-the-money-or-decimalx-y-datatypes-in-sql-server/582819#582819) but they are still more precise than the analogous integer division.

```
declare @m money = 1.9999, @m2 money = 1

select @m/@m2 /*Returns 1.9999*/

declare @b bigint = 19999, @b2 bigint = 10000

select @b/@b2 /*Returns 1*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its pretty simple; `bigint` can't hold decimal point however `money` can.

Example

**bigint** -------------- **money**

44 (correct) ------- 44 (correct) and in db 44.0000 will be saved

4.4 (incorrect) ---- 4.4(correct) and in db 4.4000 will be saved

Comment: This is wrong. Money does *not* store a decimal point, it is literally stored as a bigint. The difference is that for money SQL Server interprets the last four digits of the bigint as being to the right of a "virtual" decimal point.