# A SQL Column of type decimal rounds the number 0,01 to 0

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When editing the fields from within Visual Studio 2010, I change the value to `0,01`.

[image]

When comminiting the changes by cycling to the end of the row, it turns into a 0.

[image]

Any ideas why this happens? I need it to save 0,01 as the value. The same problem happens with the RegularCost field. I need to save something like 299,45 to it, and it rounds off.

Here's the SQL:

```
create table Auction
(
AuctionId int primary key identity(1,1),
ProductId int foreign key references Product(ProductId),
AuctionCategoryId int foreign key references AuctionCategory(AuctionCategoryId),
SerialNumber nvarchar(1024),
StartTime datetime,
EndTime datetime,
AvailableForBuyNow bit,
BuyNowCost decimal,
LanceCost decimal,
ClosingLanceCount int,
WonByUser int,
RegularCost decimal
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying [precision and scale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) like so

```
LanceCost decimal(10,2)
```

or use the [money](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933242%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) type:

```
LanceCost money
```

Comment: Spot on with the decimal recommendation.You should avoid the money type 99.99999% of the time, though.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582797/should-you-choose-the-money-or-decimalx-y-datatypes-in-sql-server

Answer (score 5):

You need to define it as

```
decimal(12,2)
```

This specifies the precision (12) and the scale (2).  If you wanted 4 decimal places, you could do decimal(12,4).

The default value is 0 for the places right of a decimal.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx