# How can I add two field values and insert them to a single column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

I have a table:

```
MTCN       Number        RecPrincipalAmount        TotalCharges
123        APK123            506.21                   258.22
```

Now I want to add `RecPrincipalAmount` and `TotalCharges` and insert them into `PrincipalAmount`.

I want this:

```
MTCN       Number        PrincipalAmount        
123        APK123            764.43
```

I want to display all these data in Crystal Reports.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I formatted your question for you (the first one's free ;) ). Why is this tagged with [tag:c++] rather than [tag:sql]? Can you provide [your attempt at doing this](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so that we can help you fix it?

Comment: Urgency isn't really a factor in this community. We aim to provide quality questions and answers that will help people for years to come. Can you please answer the questions in my previous comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
select MTCN,
       Number,
       RecPrincipalAmount+TotalCharges as PrincipalAmount
from YourTable
```

You can cast your `varchar` to `float` before adding.

```
select MTCN,
       Number,
       cast(RecPrincipalAmount as float)+cast(TotalCharges as float) as PrincipalAmount
from YourTable
```

or `money` if that is more appropriate.

```
select MTCN,
       Number,
       cast(RecPrincipalAmount as money)+cast(TotalCharges as money) as PrincipalAmount
from YourTable
```

Comment: i have done it. its not working it gives me the joined values not sum of the values.

Comment: What is the datatype of your columns

Comment: @johnsyweb i need it urgent thats why i said. this is first time im posting a question to any website so i was unaware of tags. it was done by mistake

Comment: `varchar` is an *interesting* [selection for a column containing monetary values](http://stackoverflow.com/q/582797/78845)!

Comment: @SameenYameen You should change the design of your database to use the appropriate datatype for your columns. The code I have suggested will fail if you have values in your columns that can not be converted.

Comment: @SameenYameen: I see. I have fixed the tags for you but you need to read http://stackoverflow.com/faq/#howtoask before posting any more questions.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson OMG now it is working properly.. Bundle of thanks :)

Comment: @SameenYameen: Don't forget to [mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq/#howtoask)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this.

```
SELECT 
   MTCN,
   Number,
   CONVERT(FLOAT, RecPrincipalAmount) + CONVERT(FLOAT, TotalCharges) PrincipalAmount
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a formula field:

```
//{@Principal}
{table.RecPrincipalAmount} + {table.TotalCharges}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT SUM(RecPrincipalAmount + TotalCharges ) as "You Column"
FROM Your_Table;
```