# decimal? in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, decimal, sqldatatypes

I used the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620 video to learn how to create a C# Console Application that accesses an old SQL Server database.

I have some of the fields in the database set as `Money`. The entity framework created a model from the existing database and made a property with the type `decimal?`. This makes it interesting to work with it in C# as a function becomes:

```
private static string WriteMoney(decimal? item, string output)
```

which works ok.

I can not find anything on the internet on `decimal?`. Clearly `Money` is a `decimal`, and I could fix the issue by changing the SQL database types. This is not causing a hassle, merely an interesting observation.

Anyone encountered this before?

Comment: What is the declaration of the column in SQL? I'm going to bet it allows null values.

Answer (score 2):

SQL `MONEY` is a `decimal` **sort of** type with four decimal points.
It is functionally similar to SQL `DECIMAL(19,4)`

However, it is not recommended to use the `MONEY` type if you will be doing any non-scalar arithmatic, rather you should use the appropriate `DECIMAL` type:

[Should you choose the MONEY or DECIMAL(x,y) datatypes in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582797/should-you-choose-the-money-or-decimalx-y-datatypes-in-sql-server)

This is an important differentiation from `double` or `float` which are base-2 units

As to the nullability, all SQL types can be nullable if they're set that way in the schema. If you don't want the EF to use a nullable type then you need to make the SQL field non-nullable and refresh your dbml.

Comment: I think the more important part of the question is the nullability of the decimal.

Comment: @gunr2171 any SQL type can be nullable if it's set appropriately in the schema...

Answer (score 1):

`decimal?` is just syntactic sugar for  `Nullable<decimal>`

You might want to read on [`Nullable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) if you don't know about it already.

C# doesn't have a "money" type like SQL does, so EF has to get the next closest thing, which is `decimal`. `decimal` is just a C# keyword for [`System.Decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx).

I'm guessing that your column that is of type `money` in SQL allows for nulls. That is why it is `decimal?` rather than just plain `decimal`, as `System.Decimal` is a struct and cannot be null.