# Data Type for Currency in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2012

What data type should I use to hold currency values in Entity Framework 6 and what data type should I map it in SQL Server 2012?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To have precise values, use `decimal` in C#, and also `decimal(m, n)` in SQL Server. `float` or `double` or `real` just aren't precise and will be susceptible to rounding errors - I'd avoid those.

[See this other SO question (and its answers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582797/should-you-choose-the-money-or-decimalx-y-datatypes-in-sql-server) for a discussion of *money vs. decimal in SQL Server* and why you should avoid `money` in SQL Server.