# SSRS report totals

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have an SSRS report which contains various currency entries in the form of €3340.89 stored as a string in the DB.

How can I add a line at the end of the report with the sum totals of that column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to sum them you will need to either:

- Cast them as Decimal/Money in the SQL statement.

  select CAST(REPLACE('€3340.89', '€','') as DECIMAL(10,4))
- Use expressions to convert them in the report, then sum the expressions.

My preference would be the former as it's easier to maintain.

Comment: So I have tried it in the expression of the column, `=FormatNumber(Fields!CostValue.Value)` and it displays it correctly in the table (ie: €1000 is 1,000.00) but when I add a cell with the total expression as `=Sum(Fields!CostValue.Value)` is just displays #Error

Comment: =Sum(FormatNumber(Fields!CostValue.Value))

Comment: Though if you have any bad data in the field, you will still get an error.

Comment: Yes I still get the error even with the correction above. I have tried it with a query that returns just one result, and that is displayed as 1,000.00 which is fine. I will check the values for anything odd and try it via SQL also

Comment: Hmm when I try to convert in the SQL I get this: Error converting data type varchar to numeric. I use this: `CAST(REPLACE([CostValue], '€','') as DECIMAL(10,2))`

Comment: Try SELECT ISNUMERIC([costvalue]) and see which entries are the troublesome ones.

Comment: The only thing to be aware of with Money is that it can introducing rounding errors if you perform arithmetic on it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582797/should-you-choose-the-money-or-decimalx-y-datatypes-in-sql-server