# T-Sql numeric variables error conversion

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion

It is really strange how auto convert between numeric data behaves in T-Sql

```
Declare @fdays as float(12)
Declare @mAmount As Money
Declare @fDaysi as float(12)

Set @fdays =3
Set @fdaysi =1
Set @mAmount=527228.52
Set @mAmount = @fdaysi * @mAmount/@fDays

Select @mAmount, 527228.52/3
```

The result  of this computation is

```
175742.8281      175742.840000
```

Does this occur because money and float are not actually the same kind of numeric data? Float is Approximate Numeric and Money is Exact Numeric

Answer (score 0):

> Money and Decimal are fixed numeric datatypes while Float is an
>   approximate numeric datatype. Results of mathematical operations on
>   floating point numbers can seem unpredictable, especially when
>   rounding is involved. Be sure you understand the significance of the
>   difference before you use Float!
>
> Also, Money doesn't provide any advantages over Decimal. If fractional
>   units up to 5 decimal places are not valid in your currency or
>   database schema, just use Decimal with the appropriate precision and
>   scale.

ref link :  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1408159-391-1.aspx

[Should you choose the MONEY or DECIMAL(x,y) datatypes in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582797/should-you-choose-the-money-or-decimalx-y-datatypes-in-sql-server)

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12916/datatypes-in-sql-server-difference-between-similar-dataypes-numeric-money

Answer (score 0):

`float [ (n) ]`
Where n is the number of bits that are used to store the mantissa of the float number in scientific notation and, therefore, dictates the precision and storage size. If n is specified, it must be a value between 1 and 53. The default value of n is 53.

When n in 1-24 then precision is 7 digits. 
When n in 25-53 then precision is 15 digits.

So in your example precision is 7 digits, thus first part `@fdaysi * @mAmount`
rounds result to 7 digits `527228.5`. The second part returns `527228.5/3=175742.828` and casting 175742.828 to `Money` results in `175742.8281`. So FLOAT and REAL are approximate data types and sometimes you get such surprises.

```
DECLARE @f AS FLOAT = '29545428.022495';
SELECT CAST(@f AS NUMERIC(28, 14)) AS value;
```

The result of this is `29545428.02249500200000` with just a casting.