# SQL Server 2012 Integer Division Decimal Places

Tags: sql-server

I ran the following in SQL Server 2012

`SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(7,2),4)/CONVERT(DECIMAL (7,2),3)`

and got the following.

`1.3333333333`

I believe `DECIMAL` treats 7 as precision and 2 as scale, so shouldn't I get the result to 2 decimal places?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the result to DECIMAL(7,2) too. For example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(7,2), CONVERT(DECIMAL(7,2),4)/CONVERT(DECIMAL (7,2),3))
```

This will give you:

```
1.33
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx), when you divide `e1/e2` which are `decimal(p1, s1)` and `decimal(p2, s2)`,

resulting precision is
`p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)`
resulting scale is
`max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)`

So you get precision `7 - 2 + 2 + max(6, 2 + 2 + 1)` = 13
And scale `max(6, 2 + 7 + 1)` = 10

for a result of `decimal(13, 10)`

The reason for this is that you would lose accuracy if you didn't expand the precision and scale depending on the operands: look at .5/2 = .25 and compare with .5/20 = .025.  If you use the `money` type you will probably run into this sooner or later because that has a fixed four-digit 'scale'.  For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/582819/155892

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx