# My values in money column are changed when bulk insert is used

Tags: sql-server-2008, bulk-import

I have a table where I store amount in money. When I used to insert these values from my that table to another table; values changes.

In my first table value of a column 'PRICE' is 130 but when bulk insert was used, it was inserted as 129.60 in another table.

My bulk insert command is:

```
Insert into InvoiceDetail(InvoiceId,AgentId,ProductCode,BrandId,Qty,Price,ProductType)
 Select SCOPE_IDENTITY(),'12736387',ProductCode,BrandId,Qty,M2CPrice,ProductType from 
UserPackages where AgentId='12736387'
```

Comment: Are the datatypes of the columns storing the money in both tables the same?

Comment: Yes these are same, but I think @rahul-tripathi says right...

Comment: I agree, we posted more or less at the same moment so I didn't see his answer in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use `decimal/numeric` instead of `money` as money is not precise. You can check [Should you choose the MONEY or DECIMAL(x,y) datatypes in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582797/should-you-choose-the-money-or-decimalx-y-datatypes-in-sql-server)

Do note that `MONEY` data type has rounding errors. Also performance wise decimal is better. Check the blog by Aaron Bertrand: [Performance / Storage Comparisons : MONEY vs. DECIMAL](https://sqlblog.org/2008/04/27/performance-storage-comparisons-money-vs-decimal)