# T sql cast string value as money format not working

Tags: sql-server, currency

I have values as string format below,

Values :

```
-24,52

-22,74

-13,08

303,75
```

When i **convert above string values as money** all values displays as below

```
-2452,00

-2274,00

-1308,00

30375,00
```

All values have more "**0**" number problem.How can i **convert string values to exact money format** ?

Comment: its not "money format" its money data type (basically: decimal). Formatting is a job for your UI, not your RDBMS

Comment: You should wash your data *before* casting, to avoid handling legitimate data afterwards. For the future (or even now if you can change it), if you need to store numbers in the database, don't pick a text data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to remove the 00 like this:

```
select replace(convert(varchar,cast(yourNum as money),1), ',00','')
```

Or in SQL Server 2012 you can try to use [FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

```
SELECT Format(24.01, '##,##0')
```

Comment: Replace works on string, so there is one implicit conversion to varchar

Comment: @lad2025:- Updated that!

Comment: `SELECT Format(24.01, '##,##0') ` :), `24,01` is treated as 2 arguments, use `.` for decimal point

Comment: i tried your replace method @RahulTripathi as instance: string value is -24,52 when i used your method it displays -2,452.00 .Value should be -24,5200 how can i do this like this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
select cast('-24,01' as money) / 100
```

For anything other than visual presentation its a good idea to [avoid MONEY entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582797/should-you-choose-the-money-or-decimalx-y-datatypes-in-sql-server).

Answer (score 1):

try this query

```
WITH t
AS
(
    SELECT -24.52 AS [val]
    UNION
    SELECT -22.74
    UNION
    SELECT -13.08
    UNION
    SELECT 303.75
)

SELECT CAST( ABS(t.val) AS decimal(10,2)) -- or decimal(10,0)
FROM t
```

Answer (score 1):

i tried to replace the comma with a point and got lucky:

```
cast(replace('-12,23', ',', '.') as money)
```

the reason is, sql server treats ',' as thousend delimiter instead of decimal delimiter