# Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type small money

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a column called [column_us] in my table where I have given the data type as smallmoney not null.

Initially it looked good and data is feeding into this table , but after one month I'm getting an error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric  to data type smallmoney.
> The statement has been terminated.

Do I need to change the data type to numeric (19,4) notnull to this column? If so, can you please explain which data type I should be using small money, money, or numeric?

Also how many values does the small money allow after decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is recommended to choose `numeric()` with the precision and scale you need. `Money` types may produce unexpected results when used with division (much further discussion on `money` found on this question: [Should you choose the `money` or `decimal(x,y)` datatypes in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/582797/2333499)).

`numeric`:

```
+-----------+---------------+
| Precision | Storage bytes |
+-----------+---------------+
| 1 - 9     |             5 |
| 10-19     |             9 |
| 20-28     |            13 |
| 29-38     |            17 |
+-----------+---------------+
```

`money` and `smallmoney`:

```
+------------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+
| Data type  |                         Range                         | Storage |
+------------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+
| money      | -922,337,203,685,477.5808 to 922,337,203,685,477.5807 | 8 bytes |
| smallmoney | - 214,748.3648 to 214,748.3647                        | 4 bytes |
+------------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+
```

Reference:

- [Should you choose the `money` or `decimal(x,y)` datatypes in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/582797/2333499)
- [money and smallmoney - docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/money-and-smallmoney-transact-sql)
- [decimal and numeric - docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0):

A smallmoney is not able to store big amounts, **you should use money type instead**.

smallmoney and money type are mostly used for display purpose (currency symbol, ...).
numeric or decimal types are more accurate with calculation.

You should consider searching more : I've found plenty of in depth explainations.