# Pound sign getting converted into question mark in Azure Build Pipeline

Tags: sql, azure-devops, utf-8, azure-pipelines-build-task

We have one column in our table whose name is "House€1000" but after deploying the code from Azure Build Pipeline, we could see that the pound sign got converted to "?" in Azure Build Artifacts. Can anyone suggest some something which can resolve this issue?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: hi Shruti Agrawal, and welcome to Stack Overflow. There are a few points in your question which are difficult to follow; when you say a "table", what do you mean? An azure sql database table? Or a table in azure table storage? Or a csv file? Also, can you clarify where and how precisely in your build artifact the column name is used or output?

Comment: remember, on this site you are encourage to [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70714126/edit) your question to improve it as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possibe cause is when we use non-unicode data types like  char, varchar while defining the columns.

To cover characters of all languages , there might be different number of bytes involved .
Using unicode data types like  nvarchar,nchar can covert them to UTF-8 encoded value .But they may not contain enough bytes to use that language .So try  by including the bytes involved in that particular language for that symbol to appear .ex:`VARCHAR( 270)`, currency  > decimal (19, 9) to avoid data loss through data truncation.

Enable utf encoding while preparing the columns.Some times if not enabled , try to work around by using escaping characters ex: [% ] or [^] which means % and ^.

Please go through this C[ollation and Unicode support - SQL Server | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15#converting)

**Reference:**

1. [Introducing UTF-8 support for Azure SQL Database | Azure updates | Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/azure-sql-database-introducing-utf8-support/)
2. [storing-uk-pound-sterling-in-a-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43695416/storing-uk-pound-sterling-in-a-database)