# Which datatype of C# is equivalent to money in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, model-view-controller

I am working on a project in ASP.NET MVC. I started in the middle of the project and so I got stuck in this. The data type of a column in SQL Server is `money`. I need to access that column through the model so what will be its best equivalent datatype in C#?

Comment: `decimal` is the best choice for handling `money` datatype in C#.

Comment: `money` is deprecated in SQL Server with a **strong** warning in the docs that it should never be used - since 2000. The appropriate SQL Server type is `numeric`. The equivalent .NET type is Decimal

Comment: @Tetsuya Yeah sure next time I'll make a deep search before asking.

Comment: @KovidPurohit also consider that Bitcoin has 8 decimals. The Japanese Yen none. `money` has a hard-coded precision of 4

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I can't find any reference in documentation that money is deprecated with a strong warning. Does anyone have a reference/source for this?

Comment: @DavidHoffman this is know for almost a decade. The docs have moved around quite a bit in that time. [This RedGate article](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/avoid-use-money-smallmoney-datatypes) explains why `money` is avoided: it has very limited precision, it can lead to rounding errors, it's proprietary and despite the name *doesn't* store the currency. The article's example shows how easy it is to introduce errors in even a simple percentage. `199.5/271.0` is enough to cause a rounding error with `money`

Comment: @DavidHoffman besides, [one of the duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582797/should-you-choose-the-money-or-decimalx-y-datatypes-in-sql-server) asks exactly what you asked and the top voted answer is `NEVER EVER use money`. The answers in support of `money` are simply unrealistic - where did people get the idea they don't need to multiply money in real life? How are the taxes in every bill calculated? Never mind that currencies don't just have 2 decimal digits (which become 4 decimals after multiplication). *Bitcoin* for example needs 8 decimal digits

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I have seen those articles, and I'm not disagreeing with them (I'm using decimal). Based on your comment "money is deprecated in SQL Server with a strong warning in the docs that it should never be used" I was looking for the Microsoft Sql documentation that supports that statement, because if that exists, it completely shuts down any counter arguments. MONEY seems to be a hotly debated topic, some people say NEVER use it, others say you won't get precision issues unless you're going out to larger precision values, which most people won't hit.

Answer (score 13):

`System.Decimal`. You can find other mappings in the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/sql-clr-type-mapping#NumericMapping