# c# record currency with commas and dots

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to record on a SQL Server Database a currency value with commas and dots. In this example: 80,55 in the database stays like this: 8055.

Does anyone knows how can I solve this problem?

In c# i'm doing like this:

```
public decimal ValorPlanoForm { get; set; }
```

Then like this:

```
ValorPlanoForm = message.ValorPlanoForm.ToString("G")
```

I'm using ASP.NET like this:

```html
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ValorPlanoForm">Valor do plano</label>
        <input asp-for="ValorPlanoForm" type="number" class="form-control">
        <span asp-validation-for="ValorPlanoForm"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You want to display the decimal in that format?  Or you want your SQL server data to be stored with commas?  Because storing in SQL as a decimal with commas/dots is impossible

Comment: You're storing a `decimal`, not a `string`.  Decimals are not stored in a particular format.  You can *display* it in that format.

Comment: Sorry guys my bad. I'm receving it as a decimal but i'm storing it as a string, that's why I need to store with commas.

Answer (score 1):

You can use use `DataType`

```
// Display currency symbol. For country specific currency, set 
// culture using globalization element in web.config. 
// For Great Britain Pound symbol
// <globalization culture="en-gb"/>
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
public int? Salary { get; set; }
```

Check this video tutorial in **[youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XirIE7N3-fk&index=41&list=PL6n9fhu94yhVm6S8I2xd6nYz2ZORd7X2v)**

Comment: Is it wise to store currency as an `int`?

Comment: @maccettura This was only one example. The important part is the `DataType` to change the display.

Comment: Why you want save it as string? anyway check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would store the currency data using the `Money` datatype in SQL Server, and when you want to display the data with commas and dots, you would either format it in your front end application, or using the CONVERT() function in your SELECT query.

But to answer the question you asked, if you really want to store the actual data with commas and dots, you will need to store it as a `varchar` datatype.

Comment: In fact, I'm receiving it as a decimal but i'm storing it as a string. But even so it´s storing without the commas.

Comment: Then, during the operation of storing the data from your application, you need to format the value of the variable with the dots and commas you want.

Comment: The `money` datatype is a bad idea (so i've read): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582797/should-you-choose-the-money-or-decimalx-y-datatypes-in-sql-server

Comment: I find the `money` type useful for some situations, but it's good to be aware of the limitations.