# CAST or convert Numeric to Money without rounding in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I want to convert numeric value to Money but without Rounding value.W.r.t. to 
Link : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx  It is rounding numeric to Money while casting.

But is it possible to give value upto 4 digit after decimal.
NUMERIC VALUE : 123456789.3333
MONEY VALUE OUTPUT required : 123,456,789.3333

Comment: `select cast(123456789.3333  as money)` doesn't do any rounding.

Comment: What you are describing is how you want the string representation of your data. This should NOT be done in your query. Formatting is a presentation layer concept that should only be applied in the presentation layer.

Comment: One mildly related comment is you really shouldn't use the money datatype in sql server.  It is old and imprecise (and may actually be officially deprecated).  This link does a good job of describing its issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582797/should-you-choose-the-money-or-decimalx-y-datatypes-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are looking for something like this

```
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(MONEY, CAST(123456789.3333  AS NUMERIC(18,4))), '###,###.####')
```

Result

`123,456,789.3333`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean numerics where you have more than 4 digits, then you could use `ROUND`:

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(123456789.33339, 4, 1) AS MONEY)
-- 123456789,3333
```

vs.

```
SELECT CAST(123456789.33339 AS MONEY)
-- 123456789,3334
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/LKGI48832)**

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna split number as 3 digit , you can use this code in your select command

```
Select LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(YourPrice AS MONEY), 1),  LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(UnitPrice AS MONEY), 1)) - 3 )as UnitPrice
```