# How to cut off or add decimals based on values in a filed - SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here is a sample code

```
declare @Currency table (ccy char(3),amount money)
insert into @Currency
values ('USD',12.34), ('AUD',12.34), ('INR',12.34)
```

I need to show the output as below,

```
when ccy = 'USD' then 12 (No decimals- cut off after decimal values) 

when ccy = 'AUD' then 12.34 (Two decimals)

when ccy = 'INR' then 12.3400 (Four decimals)
```

**Expected Output:**

```
 ccy    amount

 USD    12
 AUD    12.34
 INR    12.3400
```

Please advice how do I achieve this in Tsql.

Comment: Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582797/should-you-choose-the-money-or-decimalx-y-datatypes-in-sql-server  Consider using Decimal datatype instead of money.  additionally I generally consider formatting as a presentation element; not something the database does: but if you must cast to varchar with desired format.

Comment: @Jaberwocky Op specified he needs this format only for output reasons

Comment: Either way, this is beyond the scope of the money data type.

Comment: Why do this in *SQL* instead of the *client*? It's far easier to specify the decimals when formatting the value for display, eg by writing `total.ToString("N4")` where `digits is the number of digits per currency.  The equivalent `FORMAT` function was added in SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the value to a string.  SQL Server has a convenient function for this, `str()`:

```
select ccy,
       (case when ccy = 'USD' then str(amount, 10, 0)
             when ccy = 'AUD' then str(amount, 10, 2)
             when ccy = 'INR' then str(amount, 10, 4)
        end)
from @currency;
```

You may also want to investigate the [`format()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.  This allows you to include currency symbols as well.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
declare @Currency table (ccy char(3),amount money)
insert into @Currency
values ('USD',1234), ('AUD',1234), ('INR',1234)

SELECT ccy,
    CASE WHEN ccy = 'USD' THEN CAST(CAST(amount AS NUMERIC(16,0)) AS VARCHAR)
         WHEN ccy = 'AUD' THEN CAST(CAST(amount AS NUMERIC(16,2)) AS VARCHAR)
         WHEN ccy = 'INR' THEN CAST(CAST(amount AS NUMERIC(16,4)) AS VARCHAR)
    END amount
FROM @Currency
```

**Output:**

```
ccy amount
USD 1234
AUD 1234.00
INR 1234.0000
```

Check the answer in the [# SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bd5b8/1)

Comment: This is actually a good generic solution that works in almost any databases.  However, I strongly, strongly advise you to never use `varchar()` or related types without a length parameter.  The default length varies by context, and depending on it can introduce very hard to debug problems.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Thank you..! I'll follow it in the future. Thanks a lot for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CCY,
       CASE WHEN CCY=USD THEN ROUND(AMOUNT, 0)
            WHEN CCY=AUD THEN ROUND(AMOUNT, 2)
            WHEN CCY=INR THEN ROUND(AMOUNT, 4)
       END
FROM @CURRENCY
```