# Datatype for billion dollars with 7 decimal values

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the best datatype to store numeric values for billion dollars with 7 decimal values in SQL Server? Currently I am using `NUMERIC(19, 7)` however, I am not sure if this is correct because I don't have data to test it.

Comment: 7 decimals?!? You need 2 decimals to store cents.

Comment: Other than the fact that you don't need 7 decimal places for dollar amount, that would hold at least 12 digits to the left of the decimal point.

Comment: We need to store 7 decimals, that's why I have added 7 decimals.

Comment: If you need to store 7 decimals, your requirements are already more than just storing money, which makes this difficult for us to answer.

Comment: Use decimal and make sure to leave enough digits on the left part, not just for particular values but also consider month/year aggregates, etc.

Comment: Use `DECIMAL(38, 10)`.  It should be more than big enough to store all your values, and you don't have to think about the type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `MONEY` personally, which is specifically designed to hold monetary values:

> -922,337,203,685,477.5808 to 922,337,203,685,477.5807

This will handle trillions so your billion-dollar values should be fine.

Reference article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/money-and-smallmoney-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: This would be my first choice as well, but OP needs 7 decimals.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I do see that now. The originaly question did not mention requiring 7 decimals, hence my (now redundant) answer

Comment: Thanks for your response @MartinParkin. My bad I did not realize its a specific requirement until mentioned by everyone.

Comment: Money is a pretty scary datatype for anything. It can have rounding errors. I would prefer to use decimal/numeric any day. https://stackoverflow.com/a/582819/3813116

Comment: Thanks @SeanLange, I think I would stick to `NUMERIC(19,7)` as it looks like it would be a safe bet in my case.

Comment: @SeanLange This is one time I disagree with you.   Money is a perfectly valid type. After all, even decimal will round ...  Select cast(25.255 as decimal(10,2)) = 25.26

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I usually avoid the money datatype anyway because it is MS proprietary. I guess it is classified as an exact numeric so I stand corrected. :) However, I don't see the rounding error in your above example. It has to round it or truncate (or error) to fit in the smaller datatype.

Comment: @SeanLange The proprietary is a valid point.  My point is any precision would round ...  25.255 is not 25.26   It is NOT a rounding error, but it is rounded.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti agreed. Did you see the example in that link? It is off by 85¢ on a pretty simple calculation.

Comment: @SeanLange Perfectly valid point.  I may have to soften my position.   :)

Answer (score 1):

Want to cover everything? Use "DECIMAL(28,8)" it takes 4 extra bytes, but I think you shouldn't care about performance/space with those amounts and required precision.

Answer (score 0):

I would use:
for 1 to 9 billion`decimal(12,2)`,
for 10 to 99 billion`decimal(13,2)`,
for 100 to 999 billion`decimal(14,2)`.

Comment: None of these types has 7 decimals as the OP asked for.

Comment: Decimal(12,2) for numbers 1-9???? The scale of these are off the charts for the values. Oh....maybe you mean 1-9 billion?

Comment: @SeanLange yes it's bilions

Comment: Gotcha. That is not clear in your answer at all.

Comment: @SeanLange you're right!