# How should I declare smallmoney in Entity Framework code first?

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have been using the following property in my entity

public decimal smallamount { get; set; }

It persists to a SQL Server column of type `smallmoney`.

I get a warning

> No type was specified for the decimal column "smallamount" on entity type jobline.
>
> This will cause values to be silently truncated if they do not fit in the default precision and scale.
>
> Explicitly specify the SQL Server column type that can accommodate all the values using 'ForHasColumnType()'.

I gather I can use a column attribute

For example

```
[Column(TypeName = "decimal(10, 2)")]
```

Or alternatively use the modelbuilder `HasPrecision` property.

But where can I find out what precision I should use?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/money-and-smallmoney-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582797/should-you-choose-the-money-or-decimalx-y-datatypes-in-sql-server