# SQL round off issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider these values which are of type `MONEY` (sample values and these can change)

```
select 4796.529 + 1585.0414 + 350.9863 + 223.3549 + 127.6314+479.6529 + 158.5041
```

for some reason I need to round each value to a scale of 3 like this

```
select round(4796.529,3)+ round(1585.0414,3)+ round(350.9863,3)+ round(223.3549,3)+ round(127.6314,3)+ round(479.6529,3)+ round(158.5041,3)
```

but when I take the sum they shows a very minor variation. first line of code returns `7721.7000`. and the second one `7721.6990`. But this variation in not acceptable. What is the best way to solve this ?

Comment: ["The money and smallmoney data types are accurate to a ten-thousandth of the monetary units that they represent. For Informatica, the money and smallmoney data types are accurate to a one-hundredth of the monetary units that they represent."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/money-and-smallmoney-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: mathematics instead of technical, i believe. so just follow the way business requires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you round numbers before you sum them you will get a different result than if you round numbers after you have summed them. Simple as that. There is no way to solve this.

Answer (score 4):

As Whencesoever said, your problem is mathmatical one, not a programming error.

- 12.5 + 11.6 = 24.1
- ROUND(12.5) + ROUND(11.6) = 25
- ROUND(12.5 + 11.6) = 24

I'd talk with the business and figure out where they want the rounding applied.

Also, as a side note, `MONEY` is a terrible datatype.  If you can, you may want to consider switching to a `DECIMAL`.  See [Should you choose the MONEY or DECIMAL(x,y) datatypes in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582797/should-you-choose-the-money-or-decimalx-y-datatypes-in-sql-server)

Comment: if they're simply looking for a rounded total, then perhaps summing them up and rounding the result is what they're actually looking for instead of rounding each of the numbers individually?