# What is the best pairing of data types for money or currency in SQL Server and EFCore using C#?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core, currency, money-format

What is the best combination of data types for money or currency in SQL Server and EFCore using C# ?

So, for example, if you're only working with 2 decimal places, should that just be decimal in C#? But what about EFCore and the column type in the SQL Server table?

Let's say I have a class property for Price defined like this: -

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+\.\d{0,2}$")]
[Range(0, 9999999999999999.99)]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

How should this be represented in the SQL Server table? Which column type?

Comment: If you're defined a `decimal` in C# why not use a `decimal` with the same precision and scale in SQL Server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should you choose the MONEY or DECIMAL(x,y) datatypes in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582797/should-you-choose-the-money-or-decimalx-y-datatypes-in-sql-server)