# Change numeric column to money

Tags: sql-server, currency

I have values like this in my amount column

```
323547.23700
12345643.34222
```

I want to convert that in this format

```
$323,547.24
$12,345,643.34
```

I am using this

> CHAR(36)+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Amount,1)

but this is not giving me what I want

This might give a hint what I am doing

```
DECLARE @amount numeric(30,5)
SET @amount = 323547.23700
DECLARE @amount1 numeric(30,5)
SET @amount1 =12345643.34222

SELECT [USD Amount]= CHAR(36)+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@amount,1)
```

Comment: I think that might help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532351/how-do-i-convert-from-a-money-datatype-in-sql-server

Comment: @ntziolis in first case $323547

Comment: See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882.aspx)

Comment: @ADC he is trying to keep all his decimal places, money does not do that the max there is 4 decimals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ademar pointed out, you are missing the explicit length of the varchar column, this does the trick:

```
SELECT [USD Amount]= CHAR(36)+CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),@amount,1)
```

The `1` in the end should give you the desired decimal point and its values.

Answer (score 1):

We can cast the @amount to money data type first. And then convert to varchar bt specifying the style as 1.

DECLARE @amount numeric(30,5)
SET @amount = 323547.23700
DECLARE @amount1 numeric(30,5)
SET @amount1 =12345643.34222

select CHAR(36)+CONVERT(varchar(20),CAST(@amount as money),1)
select CHAR(36)+CONVERT(varchar(20),CAST(@amount1 as money),1)