# PHP Convert money to string

Tags: php

I have a piece of code that is creating a progress bar on my page to show how much a user has spent out of an allotted amount.

`$roof = 75`

`$total = 275.00` this works fine

`$total = 1,202.00` this breaks because of the comma

```
<div class="progress">
                 <div class="progress-bar <?php if($total > $roof) { echo 'progress-bar-danger'; } ?>" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<?php echo $total ; ?>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="<?php echo $roof ; ?>" style="width: <?php echo $total ; ?>%;">$<?php echo $total ; ?> of $<?php echo $roof ; ?> cap</div>
              </div>
```

How can I get this to work correctly with higher dollar amounts that include these commas?

Comment: use str_replace() to replace the comma into a dot

Comment: Where is the value of `$total` coming from? Is it dynamically pulled from a database, etc., or are you supplying it?

Comment: its coming from the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not do any logic with an already formatted string. Keep `$total` a clean integer or float and only add the decimal point and thousands separator on output.

PHP has the helpful [`number_format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function for this.

```
<?php
// Central function that is responsible to format currency
// values for display
function formatMoney($sum) {
    $formattedString = number_format($sum, 2, "." , ",");

    return $formattedString
}

$roof = 1000;
$total = 1202;
?>
<div>
    <?php
    // Format the number just for output:
    echo formatMoney($total);

    // $total remains a number:
    if ($total > $roof) {
        echo "warning";
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

With this pattern, your business logic will be independent of how a currency value is displayed to the user. Otherwise you will be in trouble if you decide to change the number formatting later (e.g. when you add localization).

If you have no access to the unformatted value of `$total` you need to parse it back into a number:

```
// Remove thousands separator and parse into a Float value:
$total = floatval(str_replace(",", "", $formattedTotal));
```

Now you can use it as a number again and use it for things like `$total > $roof`.

Comment: I stored my data in my table as "Money" so they look like this `25.0000`. This process didn't seem to work on that

Comment: If you are storing these values as strings in your database, you  want to change this. The problem is obvious: you cannot do any comparison or calculation with these "numbers". If you cannot change to application design, you will carefully need to convert the strings back into actual numbers.

Comment: I can change the front end however I need to, the data is stored as a `money` data type in the database which is formatted like this `25.0000`.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a suggestion to convert the string back into a float.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: which database are you using?

Comment: You should be able to tell SQL server how to return the value. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532351/how-do-i-convert-from-a-money-datatype-in-sql-server as a starting point.

Comment: Well I did at first, I told it to return is as `1,234.00` which is the issue I ran into. So I just left it as its normal format `25.0000` and used this to convert it ` number_format(floatval($data->totalAwarded),2)`

Answer (score 1):

Use echo number_format($total), you don't have to format it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
$total = str_replace(',', '', $total);
```

Comment: The OP wants a nicely formatted output (with thousands separator). It would do no good to _remove_ the separator. Besides, $total is supposed to be a float (real), but to format it with a thousands separator would require a _string_.

Comment: OPs problem is that comparisons like `$total > $roof` do not work with formatted output. So removing the separator would indeed be a starting point to get back to an actual number.