# How to compare SqlDbtype.Money = 0 with money field in Sql server

Tags: c#, sql

I have a SQL server 2008. The table(Items) structure with data i have is as follows:

```
ID(int)   Name(varchar(50))         Price(money)
 1        ArchBook                 1200.89
 2        Freebie                  0.00
 3        Board                    800.54
```

The datatypes of these column are in the (). I  have a select stored proc that takes price as a parameter

```
 create procedure dbo.GetItemByPrice
 @price money 
 as
 begin
 if @price = '' OR @price is NULL
 set @price = ''
 select * from dbo.Items 
 where @price = '' OR price = @price
 end
```

When i send 0 for price from C# code the result is incorrrect. I used cast in stored proc to convert it to money again after if clause.([How do I convert from a money datatype in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532351/how-do-i-convert-from-a-money-datatype-in-sql-server)) But it doesnt seem to work. Any suggestions of how i can take care of compare with 0? If price is empty is return all records.
C# Code

```
            cnn.Open();               
            string amount = "0";
            var command = new SqlCommand("GetItemsByPrice", cnn);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            var param = new SqlParameter("@price", SqlDbType.Money);
            param.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(amount);
            command.Parameters.Add(param);
            var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
               //printing columns

            }
            dataReader.Close();
            command.Dispose();
```

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In my opinion your logic is broken.**

I want to `GetItemByPrize` for price `800.54` and I will receive Items with price "". Just make `Price` field with `default value` **0** and `not allow nulls`.

**Change the procedure:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetItemByPrice
@price money 
as
BEGIN
select * from dbo.Items 
where price = @price
END
```

**EDIT:**

If you take price value from textbox for an example: Here is code example

```
decimal price = 0;

decimal.TryPrase(priceTxtBox.Text, out price);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"price", price)
```

This will guarantee that the price param will be 0 when the textbox value is "" or invalid text.

Comment: How do i handle case where i need to return all values in table if price sent was empty?

Comment: On ui price is a filter criteria. it can be empty. So i cannot make it zero explicity. I want to exclude it from SP in case if empty.

Comment: @Eve show your code ... if you want to not execute when is empty just add one if to not execute the procedure .. Add your code in the question.

Comment: My bad. Seems like i made a mistake. I cannot send empty at all after all. Is there any way you could suggest how i can take care of such a scenario? Empty as well as zero?. If filtering wasn't applied on Price column then return all column and if it were return items of that price

Comment: @Eve I will not use procedure. I will create sql select * from dbo.Items and if Price != null && Price!=0 add where clause with the condition and add the parameter in this case. In other cases I will just execute Select * from dbo.Items. Make the answer as correct if this helped you.

Comment: I got it. Finally. I figured out a way like you mentioned. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetItemByPrice
@price money 
as
BEGIN
if @price = '' OR @price is NULL
SET @price = ''
select * from dbo.Items 
where @price = '' OR price = @price
END
```

Comment: I have added set. I made a mistake in typing. This doesn't help

Comment: Did you try executing this SP from SSMS/SqlCmd? See if it's returning the correct results and then check from your C# code. If it works from SSMS and not from C# code, then please post the part of your code that's executing the SP.

Comment: From ssms. The problem is with the SP. I need to handle a case where price can be empty in which case i need to return all fields from table. And also price can  be zero;In this case i need to return all records with price 0

Comment: The problem can't be with the SP. It works on my SQL Server 2008 R2 instance. I tested it. It could be with your C# code.